# Import many files .txt in SAS

Tags: database, import, macros, sas, pipe

I built a code to import multiple data simultaneously into SAS, but I want to improve it does anyone have any suggestions?

```
filename indata pipe 'dir E:\Desafio_SAS\Dados /B'; 

data  file_list; 
    length arquivos$20.; 
    infile indata truncover ;
    input  arquivos $20.;  
    call symput('num_files',_n_); 
arquivos=compress(arquivos,',.txt');
run;
```

CRIANDO UMA MACRO POR PROC SQL PARA GUARDAR O NOME DOS ARQUIVOS

```
proc sql;
  select arquivos into :lista separated by ' ' from file_list;
quit;
%let &lista;
%macro importar(arquivo=);
filename data "E:\Desafio_SAS\Dados\&arquivo..txt";
    data &arquivo;
    infile data dlm=" " missover dsd firstobs=2;
    input v0 (v1 - v8) ($);
    format v0 F16.;
    run;
%mend importar;
%macro fileout;
%do i=1 %to &num_files;
    %importar(arquivo=df&i);
        data df&i;
        set var_names df&i;
        run;
%end;
%mend fileout;
%fileout;
%macro excluiv0;
%do i=1 %to &num_files;
    data _null_;
    data df&i(drop = v0);
    set df&i;
    run;
%end;
run;
%mend excluiv0;
%excluiv0;
```

It's just part of the code.

Comment: Hi, while you may get some feedback here, this may be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wildcard in the infile file-specification.  As long as all the files meeting the wildcard are the same layout, you can use a single input to read all the files.

Example

```
* create three text files having same fields;

data _null_;
  file '%temp%\1.txt';
  put '1 2 3 abc';
  put '3 4 5 def';

  file '%temp%\2.txt';
  put '6 7 8 ghi';
  put '9 10 11 jkl';

  file '%temp%\3.txt';
  put '12 13 14 xyz';
  put '15 16 17 tuv';
run;

* read all three using wildcard in infile.  Save name of file whence 
* data cometh frometh;

data want;
  length _filename_ $250;
  infile '%temp%\?.txt' filename=_filename_;
  length source $250;
  length a b c 8 s $20;

  source = _filename_;
  input a b c s;
run;
```

Wildcards are

- ?, 0 or 1 of any character
- *, any number of any character

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 <- ttheme_default(core=list(
  fg_params=list(fontface=c("bold.italic")),
  bg_params = list(fill=c("green", "grey90","blue","red"))))

grid.arrange(g1,
             tableGrob(iris[1:5, 1:4], theme = t1,, rows=NULL), 
             g1, g1, nrow = 2)
```

Comment: Can you explain your code such that others can learn from it?

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

````
---
title: "Column Orientation"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2);library(knitr);library(kableExtra)
library(flexdashboard);library(gridExtra);library(grid)
```   

<style>
  .colored {
  background-color: #002080;}
</style>

Column{data-width=200}
-------------------------------------

### Chart 1{.colored}

```{r}
gauge(10, min = 0, max = 100, sectors = gaugeSectors(colors = "#002080"))
gauge(50, min = 0, max = 100, sectors = gaugeSectors(colors = "#002080"))
gauge(20, min = 0, max = 100, sectors = gaugeSectors(colors = "#002080"))
gauge(15, min = 0, max = 100, sectors = gaugeSectors(colors = "#002080"))
gauge(5 , min = 0, max = 100, sectors = gaugeSectors(colors = "#002080"))
```

Column
-------------------------------------

### Chart 2

```{r, include=FALSE}
tt1 <- ttheme_default()
tt2 <- ttheme_minimal()
tt3 <- ttheme_minimal(
  core=list(bg_params = list(fill = blues9[1:4], col=NA),
            fg_params=list(fontface=3)),
  colhead=list(fg_params=list(col="navyblue", fontface=4L)),
  rowhead=list(fg_params=list(col="orange", fontface=3L)))

tab <- grid.arrange(tableGrob(iris[c(1:4,1:2), c(1:3,1:2)], theme=tt3), nrow=1)
graf <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=drat, y=disp, group=vs)) +
            geom_line() + ylab("") +
            geom_point()

gg.gauge <- function(pos,breaks=c(0,10,25,100)) {
  get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.5,r2=1.0) {
    th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
    th.end   <- pi*(1-b/100)
    th       <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=1000)
    x        <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
    y        <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
    return(data.frame(x,y))
  }
  ggplot()+ 
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[1],breaks[2]),aes(x,y),fill="forestgreen", colour = "white", size = 1.2, alpha = 0.7) +
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[2],breaks[3]),aes(x,y),fill="gold", colour = "white", size = 1.2, alpha = 0.7) +
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[3],breaks[4]),aes(x,y),fill="red", colour = "white", size = 1.2, alpha = 0.7) +
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(pos-1,pos+1,0.2),aes(x,y), colour = "white")+
    annotate("text",x=0,y=0,label=pos,vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
    coord_fixed()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank()) 
}
gg1 <- gg.gauge(2,breaks=c(0,10,25,100))
gg2 <- gg.gauge(5,breaks=c(0,10,25,100))
gg3 <- gg.gauge(7,breaks=c(0,10,25,100))

```

```{r, fig.width=9.5, fig.height=7}
for (i in 1:5){

  title1=textGrob("Test title TESTE", gp=gpar(fontface="bold", fontsize = 15))
  lay <- rbind(c(3,3,4,4,5,5),
               c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
               c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
               c(2,2,2,2,2,2),
               c(2,2,2,2,2,2))
  grid.arrange(graf, tab, gg1, gg2, gg3, top=title1,
               layout_matrix= lay)
  grid.rect(width = 1, height = 1, gp = gpar(lwd = 2, col = "black", fill = NA))

  cat("\n")
}
```
````

Answer (score -1):

````
---
title: "BRADESCO"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2);library(knitr);library(kableExtra)
library(flexdashboard);
library(gridExtra);library(grid)
```

Geral {data-icon="fa-signal"}
===================================== 

### Chat 1

```{r}
p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
p2 <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars)
p3 <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars, geom = "dotplot")
  lay <- rbind(c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
               c(3,3,3,3,3,3))
grid.arrange(p2, p3, p1, nrow = 2, layout_matrix= lay)
```   

### Table 1

```{r}
kable(mtcars[1:10, c(1:6,1:4)], caption = "Group Rows") %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  group_rows("Group 1", 4, 7) %>%
  group_rows("Group 2", 8, 10)
```   

Por segmento {data-icon="fa-signal"}
===================================== 

<style>
  .colored {
  background-color: #002080;}
</style>

Row{data-height=200}
-------------------------------------

### Chart 1{.colored}

```{r, fig.width=55}
dat = data.frame(count=rep(c(10, 60, 30),10), category=rep(c("A", "B", "C"),10), fator=c(1,2,3,4,5))

# Add addition columns, needed for drawing with geom_rect.
dat$fraction = dat$count / sum(dat$count)
dat = dat[order(dat$fraction), ]
dat$ymax = cumsum(dat$fraction)
dat$ymin = c(0, head(dat$ymax, n=-1))


p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=2, y=fraction, fill=category))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour = "white", size = 2) +
  xlim(0, 2.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#002080", "#002080", "white")) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)+ guides(fill=FALSE) +
  ylab("fsfagafs") + facet_wrap(~ fator,nrow = 1) +
  annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0, label = "WW", size = 20, colour = "white") +
  theme(
        plot.margin = margin(-1.1, 3.6, -1.1, 3.6, "cm"),
        panel.spacing = unit(30, "lines"),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#002080", colour="#002080"), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#002080", colour="#002080"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())

p
```


Row
-------------------------------------

### Chart 2 {data-wight=900}

```{r, include=FALSE}
tt1 <- ttheme_default()
tt2 <- ttheme_minimal()
tt3 <- ttheme_minimal(
  core=list(bg_params = list(fill = blues9[1:4], col=NA),
            fg_params=list(fontface=3)),
  colhead=list(fg_params=list(col="navyblue", fontface=4L)),
  rowhead=list(fg_params=list(col="orange", fontface=3L)))

tab <- grid.arrange(tableGrob(iris[c(1:4,1:2), c(1:3,1:2)], theme=tt3), nrow=1)
graf <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=drat, y=disp, group=vs)) +
            geom_line() + ylab("") +
            geom_point()

gg.gauge <- function(pos,breaks=c(0,10,25,100)) {
  get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.5,r2=1.0) {
    th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
    th.end   <- pi*(1-b/100)
    th       <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=1000)
    x        <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
    y        <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
    return(data.frame(x,y))
  }
  ggplot()+ 
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[1],breaks[2]),aes(x,y),fill="forestgreen", colour = "white", size = 1.2, alpha = 0.7) +
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[2],breaks[3]),aes(x,y),fill="gold", colour = "white", size = 1.2, alpha = 0.7) +
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[3],breaks[4]),aes(x,y),fill="red", colour = "white", size = 1.2, alpha = 0.7) +
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(pos-1,pos+1,0.2),aes(x,y), colour = "white")+
    annotate("text",x=0,y=0,label=pos,vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
    coord_fixed()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank()) 
}
gg1 <- gg.gauge(2,breaks=c(0,10,25,100))
gg2 <- gg.gauge(5,breaks=c(0,10,25,100))
gg3 <- gg.gauge(7,breaks=c(0,10,25,100))

```

```{r, fig.width=7.2, fig.height=7}
for (i in 1:5){

  title1=textGrob("Test title TESTE", gp=gpar(fontface="bold", fontsize = 15))
  lay <- rbind(c(3,3,4,4,5,5),
               c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
               c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
               c(2,2,2,2,2,2),
               c(2,2,2,2,2,2))
  grid.arrange(graf, tab, gg1, gg2, gg3, top=title1,
               layout_matrix= lay)
  grid.rect(width = 1, height = 1, gp = gpar(lwd = 2, col = "black", fill = NA))

  cat("\n")
}
```


### Chart 2
```{r}
 mydata = data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3),
                        x2 = c(9,8,7),
                        label = c("description a",
                                  "description b",
                                  "description c"))
ht = 5
wd1 = 5
wd2 = 12
gap = 0.1
nc = ncol(mydata)
nr = nrow(mydata)

x = rep(c(seq(0,(nc-2)*(wd1+gap), wd1+gap), (nc-2)*(wd1+gap) + gap + 0.5*(wd2+wd1)), nr)
y = rep(seq(0,(nr-1)*(ht+gap), ht+gap), nc) %>% sort()
h = rep(ht, nr * nc)
w = rep(c(rep(wd1, nc-1), wd2), nr)
info = as.vector(t(as.matrix(mydata[nr:1,])))

df = data.frame(x = x, y = y, h = h, w = w, info = info)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, height = h, width = w, label = info)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(color = "white", fontface = "bold") +
  coord_fixed() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual",palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = F)
```
````

teste